# Intermittently needing to re-add a version of a page

Tags: sitecore

Intermittently we are getting a message `The current item does not have a version in "English : English` when clicking on an item (page) in the content tree for Sitecore.

We click the link `Add a new version` but from time to time, we get the same message that there isn't a version.

Anyone experience this before / have an idea of the cause?

Comment: Is this occurring when there are actually no versions, or is there a problem with intermittent or inconsistent data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because we were only using a Master database and publishing to the Master DB and so overwriting and SiteCore understandably getting confused!

Answer (score 0):

This message is shown from this class:  `Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.HasNoVersions`. Can you check if you have custom code for removing versions? 
Please check if you have custom code here:

```xml
<event name="item:versionRemoved">
   <handler type="Sitecore.Globalization.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" method="OnVersionRemoved"/>
   <handler type="Sitecore.Links.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" method="OnVersionRemoved"/>
   <handler type="Sitecore.Rules.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" method="OnVersionRemoved"/>
 </event>
```

.

Comment: Yes, Im seeing code like that ... What does that tell me? We are working with inherited code, adding another site to a SiteCore instance so there is custom code,

Comment: If you say item:versionRemoved looks same like above,can you check in logs, maybe you can see something else that is removing version.

Comment: Dont see anything in the logs apart from an error Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
Source: mscorlib that seems to be do do with the Performance monitor..